# GoogleMaps API in Java

Tags: java, google-maps

Is there a good performant way to use GoogleMaps in Java Projects without using i.e. a SWT Browser.
I just know of the SwingX Toolkit (swinglabs.org) which has a quite good implementation, but it can only use OpenMaps (not the same functionality as GoogleMaps) or the Nasa BlueMarble.
thanks in advance
Lukas

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the license of Google Maps allows it only to be used on a publicly accessible web site. I doubt that your application would qualify for that.